# Retire a stake pool and get the rewards and pledge before

Tags: cardano-cli, stake-pool

I had once the knowledge on how to operate a stake pool, but I hadn't had time to care about it, and now I want to end it. Now I still have some ADA staked but also as the pool deposit thingy (forgot how it was called). Now my problem is: it doesn't run anymore because it was so old...

Is it possible to copy all files to my own computer and get the ada out of there, or do I need to update and run the pool again before I am able to retrieve my ADA which sits at the pool's address?

Please help, the docs when I google it are all with "Error 404 Page not found " which is horrible..

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can create the retirement certificate with just the cold key and a single payment utxo using cardano-cli. This can be done completely off-line on a cold environment if you know the utxo your referencing as tx-in ahead of time using `cardano-cli transaction build-raw`. It can also be done on a live environment with a running mainnet node using `cardano-cli transaction build`